# how to schedule activity by using alarm manager in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using alarm in my application.I need to know how to save its state once the application has been closed.what I want that when I restart my application the previous set alarm should exist.please help.thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do a little research before asking questions here. Read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alarm will exist even when the Activity is closed. However, it won't exist after boot, so you might want to store the desired alarm time in a SharedPreference value, then listen for BOOT_COMPLETED and set your alarm again.